# No directory /usr/cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Yesterday I updated Cygnus on my Centos VirtualMachine. Since then I had the /usr/cygnus directory where it is installed. But with the update this directory just "vanished" although the documentation say Cygnus is installed here.

All I did was a "yum update" and "yum install cygnus"

```
Package cygnus-0.11.0-1.g2a9c87f.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Have you encountered the same problem before and is there any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Cygnus did you have installed previously to upgrading to 0.11.0? We have seen similar problems with an ancient version of Cygnus that was pre-installed in an image containing a bundle of Orion + Cygnus. Such an error was fixed after 0.7.0, check it [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/329).

In any case, it should be solved by totally removing all Cygnus fingerprints at `rpm` level:

```
$ sudo rpm -e -vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers cygnus
```

Then, you can re-install Cygnus:

```
$ yum install cygnus
```